# Run batch script on system startup as specific user even if that user is not logged in

Tags: azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine, pm2, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to create a scheduled task to run a batch script on system startup as a particular user. The script will run pm2, a process manager, which will run a Node server. The Node server will authenticate to a sql server using windows auth. Right now the task is configured to run whether or not the user is logged on, and to run with the correct account, but when it tries to authenticate to the sql server it's trying to authenticate as the default VM admin account, which doesn't have access. How do I configure the VM or task in such a way that it will run the script on startup and authenticate as the correct user?

Comment: did you try `pm2 save` ? i guess that does the start all apps after system start auomatically

Comment: `pm2 save` will allow me to start that process again with a `pm2 resurrect` but as far as I know I need another solution to run `pm2 resurrect` on system startup.